# Why is it valid to access two union members at the same time in C++

Tags: c++, unions

From my understanding of C++ unions, only one member in the union is active (thus can be accessed) at any given point, and you will need a flag *outside* the union structure to determine which.

However, I recently came across the following code snippet from the fastjson library from document.h (the following code definitely works because fastjson is a widely used library, though it could be a non-standard use):

```
//! Constructor for int value.
explicit GenericValue(int i) RAPIDJSON_NOEXCEPT : data_() {
    data_.n.i64 = i;
    data_.f.flags = (i >= 0) ? (kNumberIntFlag | kUintFlag | kUint64Flag) : kNumberIntFlag;
} 

int GetInt() const { RAPIDJSON_ASSERT(data_.f.flags & kIntFlag);   return data_.n.i.i;   }
```

Where data_ is of union type Data:

```
union Data {
    String s;
    ShortString ss;
    Number n;
    ObjectData o;
    ArrayData a;
    Flag f;
};  // 16 bytes in 32-bit mode, 24 bytes in 64-bit mode, 16 bytes in 64-bit with RAPIDJSON_48BITPOINTER_OPTIMIZATION
```

Number n itself is a union too, while Flag f is a struct:

```
struct Flag {
    char payload[sizeof(SizeType) * 2 + sizeof(void*) + 2]; // 2 padding bytes
    uint16_t flags;
};

union Number {
    struct I {
        char padding[4];
        int i;
    }i;
    struct U {
        char padding2[4];
        unsigned u;
    }u;
    int64_t i64;
    uint64_t u64;
    double d;
};
```

This snippet get me confused because both `data_.f` and `data_.n` are accessed. How can this be valid? Could someone explain it to me?

Comment: Most C++ compilers allow it as extension, as C rules are more permissive.

Comment: It probably works in practice because all the overlapped data types fit into the `Flag::payload` section, so the flags are stored in non-overlapping memory. It's nasty, and non-standard, and frankly a rubbish way of writing it anyway. There's no reason to store the discriminating field inside the union.

Comment: "only one member in the union is active": on the opposite, all members are accessible at any time (just as in a struct). As the members share memory locations, modifying a member may alter the others as a side effect.

Comment: At a guess, the library author found this gave them a performance increase (one of the main draws of this library) and was willing to take a portability hit for it.

Comment: It formally has undefined behaviour.   Practically, `Flag` includes data that makes it bigger than the other types in the union `Data`, so `_data.n` and `_data.f` occupy distinct areas of memory.  If the compiler is not too aggressive with optimisation, the accesses of `_data.n` and _data.f` may not unintentionally access data from the same memory, and the program will seem to function correctly.   Problem is, the standard allows but does not require compilers to be aggressive with optimisation.

Comment: @Useless Thanks! Now I understand why it works. It's definitely nasty...

Comment: @YvesDaoust: [Doc](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/union#Explanation) contradicts you, even if most compilers allow it as **extension**.

Comment: @Jarod42: see my comment to RoQuOTriX' answer. The compilers need not do anything to allow this extension. UB does not mean "forbidden".

Comment: @YvesDaoust: IIRC, I saw a talk where that kind of invalid type punning was detected by one compiler and the code was just removed... So maybe the extension is "free" to be added, but with UB, you have no guaranty on what happens.

Comment: @Jarod42: we know that this is not portable, so a wise developer must anyway validate with all required compilers.

Comment: @YvesDaoust: And actually, compilers have to detect such wrong usages (in some contexts) [Demo](https://godbolt.org/z/zWWbc5sWf) (so it is not very costly to use that information in other context). In addition, correct (and portable) code is not hard to do, a (optimized out) `memcpy` (or `std::bitcast` in C++20) do the job.

Comment: It would be sufficient to put the flags at the front of every member, and use the _common initial sequence_  rule. It's not obvious this would be any worse than the currently fragile, fiddle, manually-aligned code, and it might actually be faster in addition to being portably correct.

Answer (score 2):

> Why is it valid to access two union members at the same time in C++

It isn't, in general.

[[class.union]](http://eel.is/c++draft/class.union) says:

> In a union, a non-static data member is active if its name refers to an object whose lifetime has begun and has not ended ([basic.life]).
> At most one of the non-static data members of an object of union type can be active at any time, that is, the value of at most one of the non-static data members can be stored in a union at any time.

and has an example describing exactly the actions of your fastjson library as *Undefined Behaviour*.

There is an **exception** to this rule:

> One special guarantee is made in order to simplify the use of unions: If a standard-layout union contains several standard-layout structs that share a common initial sequence ([class.mem]), and if a non-static data member of an object of this standard-layout union type is active and is one of the standard-layout structs, it is permitted to inspect the common initial sequence of any of the standard-layout struct members; see [class.mem].

which a developer *could* have used to make the code perfectly well-defined and portable: just put the flags at the front (of every data type), and you'll always be able to access them to find out which union member you should be using.

There is also an **extension** to this: the compiler can choose to support type-punning through unions, and in fact GCC does.

That doesn't mean it will work on every compiler, or every future version of GCC, and it doesn't make it good practice.

Answer (score 1):

> How can this be valid?

This isn't valid in standard C++. The behaviour is undefined.

> From my understanding of C++ unions, only one member in the union is active (thus can be accessed)

This is true in most cases, but is an exception: You're allowed to access common initial sequence of an inactive standard layout struct member (common with the active member). As far as I can tell, that exception doesn't apply to the shown program.